# clearing the contents of uitable in matlab gui

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

Is there a way to clear the contents of the  uitable in matlab gui like you can do

> cla(handles.axes1) % for clearing axes.

I dont want to delete uitable, just need the data to be cleared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the data:

```
t = uitable; % or however you initialize it
set(t,'Data',[])
```

or just make it invisible, the data and such are still on the table

```
set(t,'Visible','off')
```

You likely want the first, but I thought I would offer both.